# tokenize string with delimiter "/"

Tags: c++, c++11, tokenize

Hello guys I am facing a problem because I can't come up with a method that will take a string(it is actually a date in this form day/month/year) as parameter and tokenize it in a vector or an array. Could someone help out? I know that there are many topics about this but I couldn't find any solutions that don't include boost (that I dont want to use).

Comment: Why do you want to use a vector?

Comment: *that I dont want to use* -- What's wrong with boost?

Comment: boost programs may not be compilable in my teacher's computer :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to parse a date, the obvious starting point would be `std::get_time`:

```
struct tm t;

std::cin >> std::get_time(&t, "%d/%m/%Y");
```

This puts the result into a `struct tm` rather than a vector. This way you can access the day of the month (for example) as `t.tm_mday` instead of trying to remember that `x[1]` is the day, and `x[2]` is the year (or whatever).

You also get a fair number of other routines that know how to manipulate a date/time in this format, along with `mktime`, which can convert it to a `time_t` (for which quite a few more useful routines are provided).

Answer (score 1):

Here you are.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::string s( "2016/8/2" );
    std::istringstream is( s );
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    v.reserve( 3 );

    for ( std::string s; std::getline( is, s, '/' ); )
        v.push_back( s );

    for ( const auto & s : v )
        std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
2016 8 2
```

Comment: @GerasimosRagavanis I used reversed input string.:)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string parsed,input="03/12/2016";
stringstream input_stringstream(input);
vector<string> date;
if(getline(input_stringstream,parsed,'/'))
{
     date.push_back(parsed);
}
```

This parses each date character , delimited by a `/`, and puts it into a vector